# Evaluate in closed form: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, problem-solving, closed-form

Evaluate in closed form: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}$$

where $|x|<1$
I am stuck on this problem. I tried decomposing the denominator into a geometric sum and tried to use binary representations of integers but it seems to be a dead end.

I would appreciate any hints. I prefer hints to complete solutions.

Comment: Hint: $x^{2^{n+1}}=(x^{2^n})^2$

Comment: Where is x from? Hint: separate the cases $| x | < 1$ and $| x | > 1$.

Comment: @RobPratt I realized that early on, but you hinting this expression gave me an idea.

Comment: @RobPratt I can't figure it out. I am stuck. Any more suggestive hints?

Comment: $\frac{y}{1-y^2}=\sum \dots$

Comment: @RobPratt I now have solved to problem and obtained $\dfrac{x}{1-x}$ but I didn't use your hint. You may have a different solution, could you share it please?

Comment: You have obtained the solution in the case $||<1$, but you could obtain the solution in the case $||>1$ too.

Comment: Hint of RobPratt is $\frac{y}{1-y^2}=\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{1-y^2}$ and you can use his hint in the same way I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{1}{1-x^{2^n}}-\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}$$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}.$

Therefore:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{N+1}}}$$

Comment: Great work! Nice find

Comment: (+1) Well done.  All too easy.